# Error - Sharing the Same URL for two different views in exposed filter

Tags: 7, views

My goal is to prepare glossary based on contents

I have used two views, one is alphabetical search and another one is keyword search filter.

In alphabetical search, I grouped the alphabets and setted in the block and then clicking the letters, It will take to the page which contains the particular content. And here, I have used the URL is local host/glossary.

In Keyword search, Here also used the same URL (localhost/glossary), I setted the search functionality in the block and when searching the content using keywords of contents.

Its not filtering for keyword search, does only for alphabetical search.

I want to filter the both in same URL.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Glossary](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_glossary) to create a glossary that is grouped alphabetically, and then add an exposed filter to search by Keyword.

Enabling the module provides you with an example view that you can clone and modify to get the functionality you need.

1. Clone the view "Views Glossary Example" to create your `/glossary` view
2. Add your exposed filter for your keyword search.
3. Open contextual filters and change the Title filter to "Display all results for the specified field" when the filter value is not in the URL. If you don't do this, the view will only display results for 'A' when no letter is selected.

This will allow users to simultaneously search the glossary using keywords and/or filter the glossary alphabetically.